# Why does a horizontal scroll appear in mobile browser(iPhone)?

Tags: html, css, browser, mobile

I have coded a html page as follows:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#f2f2f2">

     <div style="width:1000px;height:auto;margin:0px auto;" ><!-- main container -->
         <div style="width:1000px;height:50px;margin:0px auto; background-color:pink;" ><!-- container 2 -->
           Hello world
          </div> <!-- end container 2 -->
     </div> <!-- end main container -->

 </body>
</html>
```

The width of the div is 1000px and it is center aligned using the property margin:0px auto;
When I view this in the desktop browser, it is fine. But in a mobile browser(iPhone Safari), I get an unwanted horizontal scroll, also the entire page floats hrizontally and diagonally.

Why does this happen?

How can I fix this issue which is specific to iPhone/iPad browser. I have not tested in other mobiles.

What are the code I need to put in to make a mobile browser display a webpage(designed for desktop browser)  properly?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Also I have noticed one more thing. If I hardcode the height of the main container div to 1500px or above, the problem is fixed to some extent. The scroll does not appear on load. If the iPhone is rotated to Landscape mode and then when I view in Portrait mode the issue appears. However, I cannot keep the height hardcoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions provided.

A slight modification solved the issue.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000" />
```

This worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line to head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: If I add this line, then the mobile browser screen cannot be zoomed in or out. Also, by default the webpage appears zoomed in.

Comment: I'm not expert with this but to zoom screen you should try to play with maximum-scale and minimum-scale values. By the way You should read this article: http://learnthemobileweb.com/blog/2009/07/mobile-meta-tags/. When it comes to horizontal scroll try to add to main container and container overflow:hidden. I think you should also to avoid width in px. Try to use percentage values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1" />
```

Try the above, instead. The content width is set to match that of the container div, and the max scale is removed to allow users to zoom in.